# Babylon JS assetsManager doesn't work

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I have a problem using assetsManager, if I use SceneLoader.ImportMesh everythings work:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "public/Models/", "parte.stl", scene, function (newScene) { 
        // ...
    });
```

but using assetsManager nothig works

```
var assetsManager = new BABYLON.AssetsManager(scene);
    var meshTask = assetsManager.addMeshTask("model", "", "public/Models/", "parte.stl");

    meshTask.onSuccess = function (task) {
        console.log("successo");
        task.loadedMeshes[0].position = BABYLON.Vector3.Zero();

    }

    meshTask.onError = function (task, message, exception) {
        console.log("errore");
        console.log(message, exception);
    }
```

it doesn't enter in any function, not in .onSuccess and not in .onError.

Does someone know where is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you need to call assets manager.load()

Comment: I was sureee....every time somethings like that doesn't work, it's about a stuuupid thing! Thank you very much David, and sorry for that stupid question!